# C# PulseAll doesn't wake sleeping threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a situation, where sometimes sleeping threads are not woken on a `Monitor.PulseAll(object lock)` command. The phenomenon is not deterministic. In general it works, but sometimes during debbuging, the sleeping threads fail to wake and my queue keeps filling up.

The working thread is put to sleep, if the queue is empty:

```
private void Dequeue()
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            T item;

            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (_queue.Count == 0)
                {
                    Monitor.Wait(_lock);  //thread stays asleep here. why?
                }
                item = _queue.Dequeue(); //break point [1]
            }
        }
    }
    catch (ThreadAbortException ex)
    {
        _logger.Error(ex)
    }
}
```

Upon Add the queue has at least one item and `PulseAll` on the lock-object should wake the threads.

```
public void Add(T item)
{
    Validate.NotNull(item, "item must not be null");

    lock (_lock)
    {
        _queue.Enqueue(item);
        _queueInfoAdministrator.IncrementCount();
        Monitor.PulseAll(_lock);
    }
}
```

Does anyone else have similar experiences or could point me in the right direction, as to why this happens (sometimes)?

EDIT 2011.04.08:
Further information - there is only one consumer thread. So theoretically a `Pulse` would suffice. Once the state has been reached, where the consumer thread stays sleeping, I can continue to enqueue items and subsequently call `PulseAll` without being able to wake the sleeping thread. I placed a *break point [1]*, which never gets hit in the described situation. Therefore I believe it is not a deadlock problem as described in the MSDN pages to Pulse/Monitor.

Comment: Monitor.Wait releases the lock Daniel.

Comment: You are right, didn't know that.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797892/does-monitor-wait-needs-synchronization/3798033#3798033

Comment: @Hans Passant - I don't see how that question/answer applies here. I do have a `lock` around the queue objects as you suggest in the given answer.

Comment: That question talks about the *exact* same code.  Use it or lose it, it is up to you.

Comment: @Hans Passant - it is (nearly) the exact same code, but it does not describe a solution to my problem. My `PulseAll` sometimes fails to wake the thread. Could you elaborate, how to resolve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the threads are asleep? Your code has a call to `_queue.Dequeue`, which is going to throw an exception if there are no items in the queue. So if two threads are waiting on the lock, when the `Add` method enqueues an item and calls `PulseAll`, both threads will be released. The first thread will call `Dequeue` and get the only item in the queue. The next thread will call `Dequeue` and throw an exception. If you're catching and swallowing that exception, you'll never see it.  And since the exception has escaped the `while` loop, the thread terminates and the queue will begin to fill.

Also, although I doubt this is an issue in your case, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.pulse.aspx, where it talks about potential deadlock using `Pulse` and `PulseAll`.

Comment: There is only one consumer to the queue, so I doubt that any Exception gets thrown. All the while, I would hit a breakpoint when a thread tries to dequeue an item.

Comment: The issue has been resolved through a change in architecture. I have accepted this answer, because of the information provided.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be you are pulsing when the Dequeue function is not waiting? If so the wait will not be triggered until the next pulse.

See the important note on [Pulse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.pulse.aspx)

Comment: As I mentioned above, the queue fills up. I can pulse all I want, the thread remains at the position marked with a comment. I can see that in Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 0):

the `Wait` call should always be used in a `While` loop that waits for the condition.
The original code does **not** use a `While` loop, but an If statement.

`lock (_lock)
{
    // wrong: if (_queue.Count == 0)
    while (_queue.Count == 0)
    {
        Monitor.Wait(_lock);  //thread stays asleep here. why?
    }`

for a detailed explanation see the section "Signaling with Wait and Pulse" of part 4 in this article: [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Wait_and_Pulse)